# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, DailyLeadProcessor) from the type System

Tags: apex, trailhead

I am working on the [Schedule Jobs Using the Apex Scheduler](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_scheduled) module, and I am getting the below error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, DailyLeadProcessor) from the type System

**DailyLeadProcessor**

```
global class DailyLeadProcessor implements Queueable{

    global void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx){
        List<Lead> lList = [Select Id, LeadSource from Lead where LeadSource = null limit 200];
        list<lead> led = new list<lead>();
        if(!lList.isEmpty()) {
            for(Lead l: lList) {
                l.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
                led.add(l);
            }
            update led;
        }
    }
}
```

**DailyLeadProcessorTest**

```
@isTest
public class DailyLeadProcessorTest {

    static testMethod void testMethod1(){
        Test.startTest();
        List<Lead> lstLead = new List<Lead>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i<200;i++){
            Lead led = new Lead();
            led.FirstName ='FirstName';
            led.LastName ='LastName'+i;
            led.Company ='demo'+i;
            lstLead.add(led);
        }
        insert lstLead;

        DailyLeadProcessor ab = new DailyLeadProcessor();
        String jobId = System.schedule('jobName', '0 5 * * * ?',ab);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are calling System.schedule() method by passing a class instance which has implemented the Queuable interface, whereas it expects a parameter of the class instance which has implemented the Schedulable interface.

```
DailyLeadProcessor ab = new DailyLeadProcessor();
String jobId = System.schedule('jobName', '0 5 * * * ?',ab);
```

Please modify your original class and implement **Schedulable** interface instead of the **Queuable**.

```
global class DailyLeadProcessor implements Schedulable{

global void execute(System.SchedulableContext ctx){
    List<Lead> lList = [Select Id, LeadSource from Lead where LeadSource = null limit 200];
    list<lead> led = new list<lead>();
    if(!lList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Lead l: lList) {
            l.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
            led.add(l);
        }
        update led;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trailhead asks you to implement `Schedulable` interface and not `Queueable`.

Change class definition to this:

```
global class DailyLeadProcessor implements Schedulable {

}
```